# How to check if Google Street View Image API returns no image?

Tags: javascript, google-street-view

I am using [Google Street View image API](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/streetview/index.html) to show an image of a location.

It works fine, however when no picture is available i get a black image instead of a location picture. Is there any way I can check if no image is returned and show another image instead?

Comment: Not sure why there's a vote to close as this seems to me to be a perfectly sensible question - albeit one that looks at first glimpse to not have a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to check this. The SV image API is designed for static cases when you can't add much functionality to the page.

Maybe you should look at [Street View in the JS API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview.html), which will let you detect when imagery is available.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to load the image and then compare some pixels colors. The "no streetview" image from google is always the same. Here is how you would compare 2 pixels:

```
var url = STREETVIEWURL
var img = new Image();
// Add some info to prevent cross origin tainting
img.src = url + '?' + new Date().getTime();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.onload = function() {
    var context = document.createElement('CANVAS').getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    //load 2 pixels.  I chose the first one and the 5th row
    var data1 = context.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
    var data2 = context.getImageData(0, 5, 1, 1).data;
    console.log(data1);
    // google unknown image is this pixel color [228,227,223,255]
    if(data1[0]==228 && data1[1]==227 && data1[2]==223 && data1[3]==255 && 
                     data2[0]==228 && data2[1]==227 && data2[2]==223 && data2[3]==255){
        console.log("NO StreetView Available");
    }else{
         console.log("StreetView is Available");
    }
};
```

Some potential issues: I've seen some errors with CrossOrigin tainting. Also, if google changes the image returned this code will break.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Image Div  

<div id='pano'>    

    streetview.getPanoramaByLocation(streetViewLocation, 50, function(data, status) {
                    if (status == 'OK') {
                      var fenway = {lat: Number(alarm_lat), lng: Number(alarm_lng)};
                      var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), {
                        position: fenway,
                        pov: {
                          heading: 34,
                          pitch: 10
                        }
                      });    
                      map.setStreetView(panorama);
                    }
                    else{
                      //another image here

                    }
                });
```